# How to solve the "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'"

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, twitter, python-requests-html

I'm trying to run this code below that I got from this site. However, it keeps giving "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'". (40th line) I'd be so glad if you could help me solve this issue.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
USER_AGENT = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)  
AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

def obtener_resultados(termino_busqueda, numero_resultados, codigo_lenguaje):
url_google = 'https://www.google.com/search?q={}&num={}&hl={}'.format(termino_busqueda, numero_resultados, codigo_lenguaje)
respuesta = requests.get(url_google, headers=USER_AGENT)
respuesta.raise_for_status()
return termino_busqueda, respuesta.text

def procesar_resultados(html, palabra):
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
resultados_encontrados = []
bloque = soup.find_all("div", class_="g")
for resultado in bloque:
    titulo = resultado.find('h3').string
    resultados_encontrados.append(titulo)
return resultados_encontrados

def scrape(termino_busqueda, numero_resultados, codigo_lenguaje):
palabra, html = obtener_resultados(termino_busqueda, numero_resultados, codigo_lenguaje)
resultados = procesar_resultados(html, palabra)
return resultados

if __name__ == '__main__':
palabra = 'Quantika14'
h5 = (palabra, 1, "es")

h6 = (h5[0])

username=h6
url = 'https://www.twitter.com/'+username
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')



f = soup.find('li', class_="ProfileNav-item--followers")
title=f.find('a')['title']
print (title)

g=soup.find_all('title', limit=1)
h = soup.select('.bio',limit=1)



title2 =g
print (title2)
title3=h
print(title3)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of Noneype error you can apply `if else None` statement

Example: Assuming your element selection is correct

```
title=f.find('a')['title'] if f.find('a') else None
```